# Function _Proto_ vs Prototype

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

The picture below shows that a function has a *proto* and a prototype, I understand that a *proto* is an object that is used to look up the chain. Does a prototype contain the actual prototype? Is that the distinction? Also the object A and B in this picture don't have a prototype property but I assume that if you create a prototype property it would show up on the object?

[image]

Comment: The key distinction is that `prototype` exists on a constructor, and `__proto__` exists on the instance, both pointing to the constructor's prototype.

Comment: Your picture has no A or B

Comment: What do you mean by "*the actual prototype*"?

Comment: "*I assume that if you create a prototype property it would show up on the object?*" - yes, you can create assign a `.prototype` property to any object.